# how to stop reiterating the same column name while scraping

Tags: r, col

I'm scraping a website with multiple pages and the column names is same in all pages. When I use the below code earlier the column name used to get written only once but now it is being writted multiples times.

```
  `
      n <- seq_len(5) #number of pages to parse

      for (p in n)
      {

       aa <- paste0("some website")
       remDr$navigate(aa)

       doc <- htmlParse(remDr$getPageSource()[[1]])
       Sys.sleep(2)

       docf <- readHTMLTable(doc)

        ab2<-docf$'NULL'

      write.table(ab2, "sheet.csv",
          na = "",
          row.names = FALSE,
          col.names = !(n[1]==1),### this is not working
          append = TRUE,
          sep = ",")
        } `
```

The table has 50 rows(here I gave only 8 as sample data) per page and then iteration is repeated

The table format that I desire is this [image: desired]

what the code is returning is [image: codeoutput]

can anyone help me solve this.

Comment: Write the names to the file before you start scraping, then just set `col.names = FALSE`. Or to get your current logic working, use `p` instead of `n`, i.e. `col.names = p == 1`

Comment: Another strategy would be post-processing the data if you don't wanna change the existing code. You can read in the file and get rid of duplicated rows using something like `unique`.

Comment: @Ozan147 I tried using unique but it keep the top and second iteration and removes all the other so I'll still have header is row 1 and row 10.